# Why am I not seeing colored text (only black and white) in my iTerm2 terminal?

Tags: iterm2

I'm not seeing any colors in my iTerm2 terminal (for bash, fish, zsh).  Instead, I'm just seeing black and white.  How do I fix this?  (I **am** seeing colors in the Mac Terminal app)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the `Minimum Contrast` in iTerm2's preferences.

I discovered I had set `Preferences > Profiles > Colors > Minimum Contrast` to the maximum setting on the slider.  When you do this, it shows a warning `! All text will be black or white`.  Reduce it and the colors will displayed, and will be brighter as you move the slider to the left.

[iTerm2 Preferences documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-colors.html)

[image: iTerm2 with color]
[image: iTerm2 Minimum Contrast setting]